# Is it possible to clone a test suite into another TFS server?

Tags: tfs, mtm, tcm

```
tcm suites
```

can clone suites into different team projects **within** a TFS server. I want to clone an entire suite from our test TFS server to the prod TFS server. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543843.aspx) doesn't say anything about cloning between servers. Is there a way to do it? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiment, the answer is no. You can't clone, copy or migrate an entire Test Suite from one TFS Server to another. The best way so far is to **manually** create the Test Suite with its tree structure and the Test Cases under them. Well, Too bad!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for migrate Test Suite from one TFS to another. If you only need the Test Suite (no include Test Case), you can export the Test Suite work items to Excel in test TFS and import the Excel to the prod TFS.

Or you'll need to use some third party tool to achieve your requirement, like OpsHub Commercial Utility.

Comment: Where do you export the Test Suite to Excel? I checked in MTM client, and in Web View. Web View does have an Export menu, but it only has Email, Print, Cancel options.

Comment: I mean Team Web Access.

Comment: I mean in Team Explorer/VS you can create a query and export it to Excel. In Team Web Access, you can only create a query and send as an email, in this way, you need to copy the query from email to Excel and import to other TFS.

Comment: I finally figured out to have created a query in VS and saved it to the Server. Now I can open the query results in Excel. All the Test Suites work items I want to migrate are listed. I should make the list as Tree of Work Items, right?. Now Where and how do I do the import?

Comment: Check this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

Comment: That's the page I was looking at to finish the export part. It doesn't mention how to export/import. I just tried importing by the following steps, not working exactly as I expected: 1. Create a New List spreadsheet connection the new server/Team Project; 2. copy over the exported items 3. Publish from the new Excel spreadsheet. In MTM: I can only find a new test plan and the top level test suite in the test plan. Nothing else is listed. I can search the other new test suite and test case in Web Access, but they don't have the hierarchy and all are orphaned to this point. What did I miss?

Comment: I think the problem is the query in VS. I selected Tree of Work Items but the results look flat. It doesn't show any tree structure at all, no matter how I change the query. VS version: Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3; TFS: Version 14.95.25229.0

Comment: I was planning to mess up in the test server and migrate to prod server after I get a clean version of the test suites. Without tree structure, the export/import will be pretty much useless then. It's already frustrating before I fully switch to TFS.